# Error received from server after uploading a resumable upload chunk

Tags: google-drive

I have tried to upload one 1.4Gb video to google drive by Ubuntu nautilus file app but first it woks like this :

[image]

and then this happens:

[image]

and finally, every time i tried i get this error:

```
Error received from server after uploading a resumable upload chunk.
```

[image]
My OS is :

```
lsbso@so-notebook:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
so@so-notebook:~$ uname -r
5.6.9-050609-generic
so@so-notebook:~$ uname
```

So why this happen?